# Access a custom attributes value that allows multiple use from inside context PropertyBag in NUnit

Tags: c#, asp.net, nunit-3.0

I have this custom attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class TestServer : PropertyAttribute
{
    public ServerType Sever { get; set; }
    public TestServer(ServerType server) : base("ServerType", server.ToString())
    {
        this.Sever  = server;
    }
}
```

As you can see from the code that multiple Attributes are usable on the same class. Thus when I'm going to access the property value 'ServerType' from the `TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties.Get("ServerType")` it's giving me only one value that is the first one. But it doesn't mean, the test class doesn't retain the rest.
I can even even run NUnit Test Selection Language based on these values and it even shows up in the 'result.xml' which generates after a test run

[image: here is the 'properties' section in the xml].

Can, anyone help me with this? I want to access multiple property values for the same property type from inside the 'TestContext'.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to retrieve a list of all values using the indexer notation:

```
TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties["ServerType"]
```

Comment: I found this in the function summary.

    // Summary:
    //     Gets a single value for a key, using the first one if multiple _values are present
    //     and returning null if the value is not found.

Comment: @RupanjanHari - Sorry - made a typo in my original answer! Fixed it!

Comment: Got the result of your answer. Thanks